# Why the state doesn't update in computed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm struggling for a couple of hours with vuex.
It's the first time I use it and even though I follow the documentation something is not working but I really can't figure it out.

So I have the first example of the vuex doc that doesn't work.
I have a `count` computed value that return the store state.

It's display on the page.
The started value is 0 and the view is displaying 0.
But hitting the buttons doesn't change the display.

If I put directly the store into the App.js in a constant, no problem it works.

I know I'm missing something...

homeStore.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        count: 0
    },
    mutations: {
        increment (state) {
            state.count++
        },
        decrement (state) {
            state.count--
        }
    }
})
```

App.js

```
import store from '../store/homeStore'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    computed: {
        count () {
            return store.state.count
        },
    },
    methods: {
        increment () {
            store.commit('increment')
        },
        decrement () {
            store.commit('decrement')
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Should be `this.$store.commit('increment')`.

Comment: No because its the app methods, not a component.

Comment: Tip: Install Vue plugin on chrome and check if the mutations are being fired or not.

Comment: @iRohitBhatia I have. 
I put a console.log into the mutations functions and it triggers.
I even add a button that display the store.state.count when I click on it and it works.

Only thing not working is the automatic update of the computed function in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Vuex store actions

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)
export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: { count: 0 },
    mutations: {
        increment (state) {
            state.count++ 
        },
       decrement (state) {
           state.count-- 
       }
    },
    actions: {
        increase ({ commit }) {
            commit('increment')
        },
        decrease ({ commit }) {
            commit('decrement')
        }
    }
 })
```

access the action method using this.$store.dispatch('increase') to increment the count and vice versa for decrement

Answer (score 0):

If you try to `console.log(store)`, it will returns *undefined*.
The right way to access the store is to use `this.$store` (should be a component).

[As mentioned in the doc:](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html)

> By providing the store option to the root instance, the store will be injected into **all child components of the root** and will be available on them as **this.$store**.

Therefore, your updated code should be:

```
methods: {
    increment () {
        this.$store.commit('increment')
    },
    decrement () {
        this.$store.commit('decrement')
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen that. Its needed in components, I'm not in one. I reproduced the get started demo of the documentation but I used a single file for the store.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure you can access it in that way. But you could set up this like the demo: https://codesandbox.io/embed/0owrrlo89l